# Sitecore Calendar Module 5.2 sample

Tags: calendar, sitecore, sample

I am using Sitecore Calendar Module 5.2 for Sitecore 6.5. I have been able to get it up and running. I am looking for some programmatic samples on how to read and display calendar events on a page. I haven't found any examples of this on Sitecore SDN or anywhere else either.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean version 2.4 which is for Sitecore 6.5. This module is designed to be more of a plug-n-play solution to a event calendars with Sitecore. You likely won't find any documentation on how to programatically do what you need because the module was built so you don't need to do that.

If you still want to write your own code to do these tasks, I recommend you take the following approaches:

- Decompile the DLLs from the module and review the source code for the presentation components to see how they work. Based on that, you can write your own code as needed. If you don't have a decompiler, [ILSpy is a great free one](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).
- Or, just query the content tree for the event items using Sitecore Query or Fast Query based on the architecture that this module enforces for these new templates.